# Hadoop node manager does not satisfy minimum allocations

Tags: hadoop2

Hadoop node manager doesn't satisfy minimum allocations. I am getting the following error:

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Received
>   SHUTDOWN signal  from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager
>   failed, Message from Resource Manager: NodeManager from
>   DP112.Mas.company.com doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending
>   SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.

RAM -6 GB in my physical box
And I am setting Single node setup for initial testing purpose

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: Have you found the solution. If yes then please post it

Answer (score 2):

The `"ResourceManager: NodeManager from *** doesn't satisfy minimum allocations"` error is seen when node on which node manager is being started does not have enough resources w.r.t `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` configurations.

Reduce values of `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and / or `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` then restart Yarn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have did those options too  <property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>1024</value>
</property>

Comment: I am having the same problem and I can find no precise documentation or answer that solves it. Which specific configuration parameters must satisfy which specific constraints in order to avoid this error?