# Configure Yarn with Hadoop 2.7.4 resources issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have configured hadoop 2.7.4 by following this [tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_16_04_single_node_cluster.php). DataNode, NameNode and SecondaryNameNode are working properly.

But when I run yarn, NodeManager goes down with the following message

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved
>   SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager
>   failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  localhost
>   doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the
>   NodeManager.

My system has 8 cpu with 8 GB RAM. How to configure yarn with these resources? I have found a lot such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211890/hadoop-node-manager-doesnot-satisfy-minimum-allocations) but could not find any solution that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem during a course. We were using Amazon virtual machines with **2** cores.

After various modifications in `yarn-site.xml`, we got our NodeManager running setting the following properties

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
```

In your case, you may need to establish **8** virtual cores.