# hadoop nodemanager not start ,slave doesn't satisfy minimum allocations

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

When running start-all.sh my slave1 and slave2 can't find nodemanager in jps

Work on  Ubuntu 16.04 with VM virtualbox
master

```
yunchi@master:~$ jps
15920 Jps
15505 SecondaryNameNode
15659 ResourceManager
15293 NameNode
```

slave1

```
yunchi@slave1:~$ jps
7587 DataNode
7945 Jps
```

slave2

```
yunchi@slave2:~$ jps
7138 DataNode
7374 Jps
```

this is my nodemanager-slave1.log

2017-10-12 17:26:59,662 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  slave1 doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:543)

2017-10-12 17:26:59,710 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  slave1 doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:543)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  slave1 doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:197)
    ... 6 more

I have found some relative information.They tell me to add

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>1024</value>
</property>
```

but it's still not work.

So,I set value 4096 ,still can't work

here is my yarn-site.xml below

```
 <configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>master</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>master:8033</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>master:8088</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>/home/yunchi/yarn</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I discovered that  nodemanager will  appear sometime but  few second it will disappear...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your virtual machine does not have enough resources. So you shouldn't increasing value for parameter `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, because there is no resources. Try to set smaller value for this parameter, for example 256 MB.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214293/6898608).

Comment: I saw that  a book named Hadoop:The Definitive Guide say  that yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb can't not smaller than 1024

Comment: Yes, you are right, it shouldn't be smaller. But what if you do not have enough resources? If you don't want to set smaller value than 1024 MB, then you have to give more resources to your virtual machine. If you can't do it - you have to set smaller value for this parameter. If it is not your production environment, but rather sandbox - don't be afraid to set smaler value. At worst - it won't work.